# Not able to click on Check box using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on the check box, but my code is not working. Steps which I want to follow is

1. Open website
2. Select Profession e.g:- Dental
3. License Type e.g :- Dentist
4. Enter a alphabet with * to get all the records
5. Click on the check box
6. Click on search button

Script also ask for image verification for which I am unable to process, any help would be appriciated

```
home_page = 'https://forms.nh.gov/licenseverification/'
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import csv
from shutil import copyfile
import datetime
import subprocess
import time
import multiprocessing
import sys
import subprocess
current_date=datetime.date.today()
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\psingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(home_page)

select_prof = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "t_web_lookup__profession_name")))

Select(select_prof).select_by_value('Dental')

select_lic_type = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "t_web_lookup__license_type_name")))
# select profession criteria value
Select(select_lic_type).select_by_value('Dentist')
time.sleep(1)

send = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "t_web_lookup__last_name"))
)
send.send_keys('A*')
time.sleep(1)
# click on check box
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]").click()
# click search button
driver.find_element_by_id("sch_button").click()
# wait to get the result
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: At which line are you stuck? What error do you see?

Comment: The checkbox which you are trying to click is a captcha, which is inside a frame. Add this line before clicking to checkbox, driver.switch_to.frame(0) , your code will click on the cpatcha check box. Let me know if it doesn't work for you. Learning Tip: If you have selenium IDE, try to record first your scenario with it. You can easily see that the element is inside a frame or window. Or if you stuck like this, in your dom, search frame or iframe.

Comment: stuck in the this line driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]").click()

Comment: @PushpendraSingh Added as answer. The xpath, which you were using to click on checkbox is incorrect. It is highlighting 3 elements in DOM. To check that your locator (xpath etc) is correct, check in DOM, that is it highlighting the correct element or not. Way to do this: CTRL+SHIFT+I (or open developer tool( in browser->Click on Elements tab -> Mouse hover to your element -> Right click -> Click on Inspect

Comment: @QualityMatters Thanks you. Got the solution. Issue was with iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check box which you are trying to click is inside the iframe. First switch to that iframe and then try to click on that checkbox.

Below code works fine in pycharm and windows 10.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH) 
url = 'https://forms.nh.gov/licenseverification/'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
sleep(5)

select_prof = driver.find_element(By.ID, 't_web_lookup__profession_name')
Select(select_prof).select_by_value('Dental')

select_lic_type = driver.find_element(By.ID, "t_web_lookup__license_type_name")
# select profession criteria value
Select(select_lic_type).select_by_value('Dentist')
sleep(1)

send = driver.find_element(By.ID, "t_web_lookup__last_name")
send.send_keys('A*')
sleep(1)
# click on check box
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
captcha = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.recaptcha-checkbox-border')
captcha.click()
# click search button
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "sch_button").click()
sleep(1)
```